# multiple gridviews in a single Activity/fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview

I would like to have two or more gridviews on a single activity/fragment so for instance, i have a textview and a gridview, so when i click on a button in this activity the current gridview disappears and replaces it with new gridview, however i want the textview to stay there and not loose the text inside the textview.